# How to create the AVD for Android 2.3 - API 9

Tags: android, sdk, android-virtual-device, simulator

I need to run the Android simulator with the 2.3 version (API 9) but I don't have this version available in the Android SDK Manager.

Currently I can install API 7, 8 and 10 up to the 19, but not 9.
Is there any way to run a simulator with this version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android API 9 is obsolete, and is not selected for downloading by default. You can access/select it by checking the "Obsolete" checkbox near the bottom of the SDK Manager.

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile a friend told me that there is a checkbox in the android sdk manager, named obsolete, that enables the installation of these old versions.